# how to call object arrow function in JavaScript where object returns

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
   return {
        init: () => {
             console.log('init')
        },
        run: () => {
            init()
        }
    };
```

how to call init function from run function
as code is already developed and cant modify need to call like this only

Comment: why not call init directly? `function().init();`

Comment: You want to change the behavior without modifying the code?

Comment: i have modified the same like this and its working fine.

run: function () {
     
      this.init();
    }

Comment: return() => {
        init: () => {
             console.log('init')
        },
        run: () => {
            init()
        }
    };

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```js
var someObjectName = {
    init: () => {
         console.log('init')
    },
    run() {
        return this.init()
    }
};
someObjectName.run()
```

or

```js
var someObjectName = {
    init: () => {
         console.log('init')
    },
    run() {
        return this.init()
    }
}.run();
```

Comment: Why are you using a getter?

Comment: @FelixKling Updated the answer, before I wasn't able to make it work without getter, but now it works